# Sitecore Redirect Rule Loses Language Code in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, sitecore8, http-redirect

I'm a `Sitecore` developer trying to set up a Redirect Rule.  I'm using the
[301 Redirect Module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/3/301_Redirect_module.aspx?sc_lang=en)
tool and, I think the concept is similar to typical `Sitecore` redirects.  In our TEST `Sitecore CMS`, I have created an item of type `Redirect Rule`, with a `Response Status Code` set to `301 Moved Permanent`, which has the following redirect rule:

```
where the URL contains Jan2017 replace the static Jan2017 with the static
2017/01
```

This successfully redirects 
https://test.willistowerswatson.com/de-DE/press/**Feb2017**/bAV-Reform-BR-Ausschuesse to https://test..willistowerswatson.com/press/**2017/02**/bAV-Reform-BR-Ausschuesse

The only problem is, why is the language code `de-DE` lost?

I would like to maintain the language code of source `URL` in the destination `URL`.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting languageEmbedding property to 'always'?

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
<providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="sitecore" ... languageEmbedding="Always" ... />
</providers>
```

The languageEmbedding options are:

- asNeeded
- always
- never

Changing the config to use languageEmbedding="never" will stop the language from showing up in the URL, and likewise languageEmbedding="always" will force the language to always show up in the URL.